# Angular full calendar - more information during selecting

Tags: angular, fullcalendar

I have question about select functionality that has been implemented by full-calendar. When I’m selecting I see only the information about hours (start time - end time) in real time. I would like to see more information ex. duration or custom text during selecting.

https://www.kapwing.com/videos/62f6655d6f728500f29ff29f

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-vhsnzk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,package.json,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts,tsconfig.json

Comment: I would recommend; 1) anyone reading this, don't click random links (at least not with JS enabled) 2) ngx, please do not use links, if you have code to share, do so here as a [mre], please do not post links to external resources

Comment: Duration is trivial to calculate using the start and end times, if you need to. As for custom text, I don't really know what you mean- the user has no opportunity to type anything during the selection process, so I'm unsure what you're expecting with this. If you want the user to type in a title for your event, you can add some extra UI to do that once they've made the initial selection

Comment: @CanO'Spam which link are you concerned about? Stackblitz is legit, good way to share runnable code for frontend projects which need a build process. It's true the OP should share relevant code here as well for the record (although arguably this specific question doesn't especially need any) but there's nothing wrong with a link to that site for a runnable version. I can't comment on the other link, presumably some random video sharing thing - I agree I wouldn't click it without more research, and it's unclear how it's useful for the question anyway.